# I have an image which i would like to have grow everytime i click a button

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway i could scale an image to become 1.25x bigger everytime a button is pushed?
Basically, could someone give me some tips on how to do this? An explanation, a link, a tutorial, anything would be helpful :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this.

http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html

Here is code from this page. It creates a Matrix to perform operations(resize and rotate) and applies that matrix to create new BitMap.

You can add the code(with some modifications) on `OnClickListener` event of yout Button.

```
public class bitmaptest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        // load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               R.drawable.android);

        int width = bitmapOrg.width();
        int height = bitmapOrg.height();
        int newWidth = 200;
        int newHeight = 200;

        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // createa matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // rotate the Bitmap
        matrix.postRotate(45);

        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                          width, height, matrix, true);

        // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap
        // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        // set the Drawable on the ImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);

        // center the Image
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

        // add ImageView to the Layout
        linLayout.addView(imageView,
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                )
        );

        // set LinearLayout as ContentView
        setContentView(linLayout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` to resize image.
Refer to my articles on `Image Processing` to get some idea :): https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/

Comment: your articles? where may I find them?

Comment: A link would be handy. I assume you mean your site, so I took a quick look at http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/tag/image/ but couldn't seen any articles on re-sizing.